# Duplicate windows service, different name and location - will not start

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service that has it's name set by an app.config.
I set the name as follows:

The ServiceBase.SerivceName is set on the Service class constructor (I have removed the setting of the ServiceName in the Service.Designer):

```
ServiceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ServiceName");
```

The ServiceInstaller sets the DisplayName and ServiceName like this:

```
ServiceInstaller.DisplayName = config.AppSettings.Settings["ServiceName"].Value;
ServiceInstaller.ServiceName = ServiceInstaller.DisplayName;
```

All works as expected, so the service is installed fine alongside a duplicate service.
They have different names and different locations.
The appear as seperate entries in the Services list.

But I can only start one service at a time. The error I get on trying to start the second service is the unhelpful:

```
The service is not responding to the control function.
```

There are 2 System Events that get logged when trying to run:

```
A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the Blah Service service to connect.  

The Blah Service service failed to start due to the following error:
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Any help gratefully received.

Thanks.

Comment: Anything useful in the event log? Are you inadvertently trying to share a non-shareable resource?

Comment: I've edited the question and added the 2 System Events that get logged. As the services are being installed from 2 seperate folder locaitons, i don't THINK they are sharing any resoures. Thanks.

Comment: I would put some logging in your OnStart and see if it's getting hit.

Comment: Yeah fair point. I tried that and it wasn't getting hit. Nor was the static constructor...

Comment: Anything funky in your constructor? You shouldn't really do any initialization in there for a service.

Comment: Only setting up the Log Manager - but it doesn't get that far anyway.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9307/discussion-between-glasto-red-and-james-world)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of sufficent info to offer an answer to the problem at hand, I suggest using http://topshelf-project.com/ - it makes installing, configuring and debugging windows services in .NET a breeze.

Comment: Note that TopShelf doesn't support multiple instances of Windows services as per their documentation. However, don't let that stop you. See more here: http://clarify.dovetailsoftware.com/kmiller/2009/09/24/running-multiple-instances-of-a-windows-service-using-topshelf/